# Adding input variable inside regex

Tags: python, regex, input

I'm trying to make a code that finds all preferred file extension and then moves them to designed folder. Code is working but I need to enter file extensions manually inside the file. What I'm trying to do is add an input variable and place it into re.compile(), therefore I don't need to edit the file whenever I need it for different file types.

This part I need to edit:

```
# Go through the listFiles and find specific file types.
picRegex = re.compile(r'.*\.jpg|.*\.png')
fileMatches = list(filter(picRegex.match, listFiles)
```

This works for the filetypes already there in my code but as I said I want it to be more flexible. Is there any way I can improve this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to pass the regex string to your file from externally, i.e. from the command line?

Comment: Yeah, what I want is when I double click the py file prompt asks for input that the file extension I wanna move. @ColeRobertson

Comment: Can't you just use standard string formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the regular expression with string methods:

```
file_extensions = ['.png','.jpg']
regex = '.*(%s)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, file_extensions))
filename_matches = list(filter(re.compile(regex).fullmatch, filenames)
```

Better, don't use regular expressions at all, but `endswith`:

```
file_extensions = tuple(['.png','.jpg'])
filename_matches = [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(file_extensions)]
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely gonna play with these examples.

Comment: `# Go through the os.listdir and find specific file types.

fileExtensions = []
y = input('Please enter file extension with a dot(like .txt): ')
fileExtensions.append(y)
fileExtensions = tuple(fileExtensions)
fileMatches = [file for file in listFiles if file.endswith(fileExtensions)]`

I come up with this, It's working but Idk if it's written effectively...

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are just strings you pass to `re.compile` and friends. The full palette of Python string formatting is at your disposal.

Perhaps something like this, then?

```py
picPegex = re.compile('|'.join([r'.*\.{0}'.format(x) for x in ('jpg', 'png')]))
```

If you always need these at the end of line, though, maybe simply

```
if thing.endswith(tuple(['.{0}' for x in ('jpg', 'png')])):
    print('yowza')
```

Comment: don't format strings into regular expressions without `re.escape`.

Comment: That's not bad advice, but perhaps an overcomplication if the input is just a file extension.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a beginner and that endswith() method looks interesting too, I need to take a look at it.